# The best way to update site from SVN server without SVN client on live site

Tags: svn

We have SVN server on out intranet (192.168.x.x) for me and my fellow developer to develop our site (202.6.x.x). My problem is, my live server doesn't have `svn` command installed. This live server can't access SVN server as it don't have public IP. What is the best way to deploy our site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a simple PHP script to execute on the command-line of your SVN server (or any other server that can run SVN and access your intranet SVN server). This script can ensure a working copy has the latest revision (using `svn update`), then it can run an `svn export` to remove all the .svn metadata. You could then FTP/SFTP upload this exported structure to the live server, using curl or any other PHP lib.

You could also get really clever and use a **post commit hook** on the SVN server to do this automatically for you everytime a new revision is committed :)

Comment: hmm.. post commit hook. New to me, I'll google it first. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Write a build script and use in combination with a Continuous build server like [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ant and write a script with a target (you can use ant tasks, scp and sshexec) to deliver the package required to your destination server.